# How to use Import Report API in Power BI

Tags: powershell, api, rest, https, powerbi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/post-import-in-group is what I am trying to implement in PowerShell to publish a local report to Power BI Service. When I try this API it shows 400 Bad Request error.

```
$accessToken = Get-AccessToken -ClientId "{client_id}" -ClientSecret "{client_secret}"

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
}

$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary")

$body = @"
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"report.pbix`"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
--$boundary--
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/imports" -Headers $headers -Body $body
```